# Android: Can you exploit a broadcast Receiver that receives a custom object from the intent?

Tags: android, mobile, java

The app I am trying to attack (under a legitimate bug bounty program of course) has the following code for its broadcast receiver:

```
//From vulnerable app
public void onReceive(Context paramContext, Intent paramIntent)
  {
...
paramIntent = (CommonBean)paramIntent.getSerializableExtra("msg_bean");
```

After the serializable extra is retrieved from the intent, it is casted to the type CommonBean, which is a custom class defined in the app. I tried redefining the CommonBean class in another attacking app and instantiate the object. It is then passed into the intent before sending it to the receiver as shown in the code below.

```
//From attacking app
CommonBean bean = new CommonBean();
intent.putExtra("msg_bean", bean);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

However, I got a ClassDefNotFound Error as the classpath of the attacking app is different from the vulnerable app. (i.e If the attacking app has package a.b.c and the vulnerable app has the package d.e.f, the vulnerable app will raise a ClassDefNotFound Error as a.b.c.CommonBean cannot be found in the vulnerable app, where the CommonBean class is supposed to be d.e.f.CommonBean instead). Is there any way to pass this custom object to the intent so that the path of the object follows the vulnerable app (d.e.f) and not the attacking app?(a.b.c)

Comment: The attacking app's classes are not in the vulnerable app's process.

Comment: Although I didn't get what you want to do as here the attack scenario is not clear. But you can redefine CommonBean class in the attacking application and can use the implementation defined in the victim application, set the values as you want. After instantiating the object you can send it in an intent.